# Is there a math description of a generalized row major

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Im looking for a generalized term for the classical row/column major order.

In principle its just a discrete rectangular space $V \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, where we assign a scalar to each point by multiplying it with a vector $\lambda$.

Is there any term for describing the required property for $\lambda$, in order to have a generalized row/column major order?

Note: The assigned values are not necessarily dense.